# Websocket get user profile from request header

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, passport.js

for a normal http request I can configure `passport.js` so my http server can read the request header and deserialize the correct user profile.

```
app.route('/login').post(function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', {}, function(err, user){
        if (err) return res.json(500, {error: err.toString()});
        return res.send({user: user});
    })(req, res, next)
});
```

but for a websocket connection I can see the session id in the request header but how do I combine this with `passport` to fetch the correct user profile? 
I used `request` module to call corresponding API routes but I feel like I am taking a detour...

```
var server = http.createServer();
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server })

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  // connected and can see the request header here...

  var cookie = ws.upgradeReq.headers.cookie;
  /* cookie is something like this.
  cookie = {
    aaa: aaa
    bbb: bbb
    'connect.sid': 's%3A4Cxxxx'
  } */

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    ws.send('your message is: ' + message);
  });

});
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at passport-socketio which works for socket.io but it could give you an idea how to do the same with websockets